# In a Category, Is the Set of Morphisms Between Objects Defined to Be All Possible Morphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For instance, if I have a category $\mathfrak{M}$ whose objects are families of morphisms $\{f_i\colon A_i\to B\}_{i\in{I}}$, then if we consider two such objects, say $C=\{f_i\colon A_i\to B\}$ and $D=\{f'_i\colon A_i\to B'\}$, can I define $\text{Mor}(C,D)$ to be morphisms $\varphi\colon B\to B'$ such that $\varphi\circ f_i=f'_i$ for any $i$? This does preserve structures because it takes a family of morphisms to another family of morphisms. Does $\text{Mor}(C,D)$ necessarily mean *all* possible morphisms that preserve structure? If it does, then I don't think I can restrict the morphisms of this category as I have, correct?

Comment: Beware: The collection of morphisms from one object to another in a category need not be a set. If it happens to be a set for each pair of objects in a category, then that category is called "locally small". Of course, many of the most commonly encountered categories _are_ locally small.

Comment: Your title for the question presupposes that the morphisms are taken from some already existing bag of morphisms. This is not the case. The morphisms in a category are not necessarily structure preserving functions. In fact, they don't need to be functions at all. Understanding that should nullify the entire question. You can define a category anyway you like as long as the axioms hold.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only restrictions on morphisms are that an identity morphism must exist for every object and composition of morphisms must be associative. Other than that, morphisms may be defined as you choose.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!